# SQL AlwaysON Turkish Collation Problem During Setup

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, collation

I have 2 servers with SQL Server 2014 SP2 and windows 2012 R2 installed on them. 
When I tried to create availability group it failed with

> the primary replica is not active

But when I tried to create availability group with different collation other than `turkish_ci_as` it worked.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are sure both instances had the exact same collation?

Comment: Yes, both instances had same collation which is TURKISH_CI_AS

Comment: Availability Groups are logical containers for databases that fail over as a unit - they don't have collation settings, so I am a little confused on what you mean by `But when I tried to create availability group with different collation other than turkish_ci_as it worked.` Please update the question with an example.

Comment: When i install sql server with latin1_general_cp1, i can create an availability group between server1 and server2. But if have choose turkish_ci_as collation while installing sql server then i can't  create availability group, it stucks joining availability section and then throw this exception "the primary replica is not active"..

Comment: @user2768544 What is the language setting at the OS level? I assume it isn't Turkish. I would try making sure that the language at the OS level, and maybe even the language of the SQL Server instance itself, are Turkish.

Comment: Can you confirm that when using `Turkish_ci_as` the server names do not equate to each other? ex: when using Turkish the server names shouldn't compare equal.